# Поворот вектора относительно второго

Tags: математика, векторы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
private Vector2 GetRotationVector (Vector2 target, Vector2 axis)
{
    var tRad = Atan2(target.y, target.x);
    var aRad = Atan2(axis.y, axis.x);
    var rad = tRad+aRad;
    return new Vector2(Cos(rad), Sin(rad))*target.GetDistance();
}
```

Можно как-то проще?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так можно довернуть `target` на угол заданный `axis`:

```
private Vector2 GetRotationVector (Vector2 target, Vector2 axis)
{
    axis /= axis.GetDistance(); // Normalize
    return new Vector2(target.x * axis.x - target.y * axis.y, target.x * axis.y + target.y * axis.x);
}
```

1. Если вы знаете комплексные числа, то при произведении двух чисел их аргументы складываются, а модули умножаются. Сперва мы получаем число с единичным модулем, затем умножаем на него `target`. В итоге `target` повернётся на нужный угол, но не изменит свой модуль.
2. Если вы не знаете комплексные числа, то смотрите тригонометрические формулы для суммы углов.

Comment: Комплексных чисел не знаю.  `Atan2`, `Cos` и `Sin` нет, а посчитать дистанцию все равно придется 

Comment: На тему проще. Именно из-за подсчета длины вектора я и задался вопросом альтернатив.

Comment: Или `axis` будет единичной длины, или его придётся нормировать. Без вычисления длины никак.

Comment: Ну не 3 раза как через сумму радиан, каждый `Atan2` это вычисление корня, если я не ошибаюсь. Спасибо!

Comment: Ваш последний вариант портит параметр `axis`. Это подразумевалось?

Comment: Нет, если это `Vector2` это `struct`, там просто было `a.GetDistance()`, что за `a` не понятно, у меня была ошибка, вы скопировали) у меня было `a` вместо `target`, как вектор `A`, у вас `a` вместо `axis`, путаница.